# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Clue` model once compiled. Mongoose NextJS

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to build a simple web app with NextJS and trying to incorporate Mongoose for my DB operations.

This is the error I see:
[image]

I've read through the countless StackOverflow posts already but none of their solutions seem to work.

So my NextJS project is structured like this:

I have my `app/page.tsx` as such. Since I have a lot of components that rely on window sizes, I render the `App` component with a `{ssr: false}`

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const App = dynamic(() => import('../components/App'), { ssr: false })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <ChakraProvider>
          <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </main>
  );
}
```

One subcomponent within my app is the `components/Game.tsx` which is as follows. (The `Clue` here is a basic type).

```
import { Clue } from "../types";
import { getDailyClue } from "../api/ClueAPI";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Game = (props: {color: string}) => {

    const [clue, setClue] = useState<Clue>();

    useEffect(() => {
        getDailyClue().then((clue) => setClue(clue));
        console.log(clue);
    }, [clue]);

    return (
        <> Stuff </>
    );
}

export default Game;
```

For the interesting part, the `getDailyClue` is where I need to connect to my MongoDB database and make a query.

First is the `api/DBApi.ts` with the code to connect to Mongo.

```
'use server';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I have my `api/clue.ts`, which creates the model.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const clueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rowid: Number,
    clue: String,
    ...
});

export default mongoose.models.ClueModel || mongoose.model('Clue', clueSchema);
```

And lastly, I have the code that fetches data in `api/ClueAPI.ts`

```
'use server';

import { Clue } from '../types';
import { connectDB } from './DBAPI';
import ClueModel from './clue';

export const getDailyClue = async (): Promise<Clue> => {
    await connectDB();
    const randomClue = await ClueModel.find([
        {
            $match: {
                date_used: {
                    $lte: new Date('2000-01-01'),
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
    return randomClue[0];

};
```

My understanding is that the error happens when I try to fetch the data from mongoose. I'm fairly new to NextJS and trying to get my foundations up with this small project I'm building.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch more of stuff and looks like these changes in my `api/clue.ts` worked:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const clueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    rowid: Number,
    clue: String,
    ...
});

const getModel = () => {
    return mongoose.model('Clue', clueSchema);
}

const ClueModel = mongoose.models.Clue || getModel();

export default ClueModel;
```

I suppose the primary fix was using `mongoose.models.Clue` instead of `mongoose.models.ClueModel.`